# How can I share existing folder without going to the user

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, file-sharing, network-share

I would like to know if there a way to share folders on a remote machine with out having to be in front of it. For example I have user1 and he has folder called TEST and he asking me to share it. How can I do it from my computer or from group policy or something like that without go to his PC?
Note: I'm administrator on the network
Any advice would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Please go back to your previous questions and accept the answers that helped you. Thanks!

Comment: OK I found it and I make all the questions as accepted

Comment: Click on your name. You should be able to see your questions on your profile. Go through your questions and if one is the correct answer, click on the check mark. It's the best way to say thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this through **Computer Management**. Choose **Action > Connect to another computer**. Under **System Tools** you have **Shared Folders**. Right click on the **Shares** folder under it and choose **New Share**.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **start > run mstsc** (remote desktop)

Or you could use the method Nixphoe mentioned.

Comment: I wanted to double check the Start > Run \\computer as you mentioned. I tried this through the c$ share. I have access to security rights, but you can not share through accessing the computer that way. RDP would work though :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to navigate to the folder, right click on it, hit Properties, and go to Sharing and Security. As a Domain Admin you should have access to everything.

Comment: Yeah you are right but this way I have to go physically on the PC but I wanted over network without log out the user and logon with my user. Imagine you ask me to share something and from my seat I do the share without log you out.thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Ohhh! If it's XP Professional, Vista Business/Ultimate/Enterprise, or Windows 7 Professional/Ultimate/Enterprise, you can use Remote Desktop Connection, provided it's enabled.

Comment: My users using XP Professional and it's not good idea because I will log them out and you know they have to save all docs and close all apps so how I do it without log them out?

Comment: There are other remote desktop programs out there that won't log out the user, like VNC.